# Cannot get tab title

Tags: javascript, kango-framework

I am working on a browser extension for which I need to know the current tab title. I manage to find the title from the the HTML page code but, from after documenting more about this I have found that there are easier ways to do this.

I have tried the following ways:

```
selectedTabTitle = $(ui.tab).text();
```

and

```
selectedTabTitle = document.title;
```

but neither work. I must note that I am using kango-framework to make this extension.

Comment: What "tab" are you talking about?  Your 2 examples are *COMPLETELY* different!  One is about jQuery UI tabs and the other is the browser's tab.  What *exactly* are you trying to get?  Where are you trying to access it?  What is `ui`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat , browser's tab.

Comment: What browser are you making an extension for?

Comment: Firefox at the moment.

Comment: Firefox extensions use a different method of accessing tab titles.  For Firefox, see: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html (Chrome is competently different)

Answer (score 2):

`document.title` should work or `$('title').text()`

are you maybe working with iframes? In that case the title of the iframe will be returned.

here an example:

first one shows the code, second one, so that it is not launched in an iframe

http://jsfiddle.net/56deD/

http://jsfiddle.net/56deD/show/